# How do I access PowerShell object values?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I currently have an Azure DevOps pipeline that makes a REST API call which returns an object of parameters:

```
@{location=eastus2; envName=sandbox; ...}
```

My PowerShell script looks like:

```
steps:
  - powershell: |
      $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{proj}/_apis/build/latest/{buildId}?branchName={name}&api-version=6.0-preview.1"
      $token = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("$(System.AccessToken)" + ":")
      $base64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($token)

      $basicAuth = [string]::Format("Basic {0}", $base64)
      $headers = @{ Authorization = $basicAuth }
      
      $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -ContentType application/json
      $params = $result.templateParameters

      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=paramObj]$params"
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host $(paramObj)
```

In this first PS task I can use `$params.location` which will return eastus2. However, in the second PS task I get an error saying:

```
Line |
   2 |  Write-Host @{location=eastus2; envName=Sandbox; sqlDBAutoPauseDatabas …
     |                        ~~~~~~~
     | The term 'eastus2' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet,
     | function, script file, or executable program. Check the
     | spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
     | the path is correct and try again.
```

Since my API call has an object of parameters, I'm trying to pass that parameter object to another task where I can then use those values. In the second task seen above I can't log the result, so of course trying to use dot notation, or Select-Object all results in the same error.

I was also attempting to iterate over the parameters object so I could do something like:

```
steps:
  - powershell: |
      ...
      $params = $result.templateParameters

      foreach ($param in $params) {
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=test]$param.Value"
      }
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host $(location)
```

But I haven't been able to figure this out either as I keep getting the same error listed above. How do I access the parameter values in a second script without hardcoding it?

Comment: Change `"##vso[task.setvariable variable=test]$param.Value"` to `"##vso[task.setvariable variable=test]$($param.Value)"` <- otherwise PowerShell tries to expand `$param` on it's own (without evaluating `.Value`)

Comment: In short: In order to embed _expressions_ in an expandable string (`"..."`), you must enclose them in `$(...)`. Notably, this includes property and indexed access (e.g., `$($var.property)`, `$($var[0])`). Only variables _as a whole_ do not require this (e.g., `$var`, `$env:USERNAME`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) to the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You've encountered the magic of [expandable string parsing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2#double-quoted-strings) in PowerShell.

When you place a variable expression, like `$param`, inside an expandable string (a string literal bounded with `"` double quotes), PowerShell will attempt to resolve it's value for you - but nothing more than that - it's **not** going to attempt to evaluate member invocation, like `$param.Value`, for example.

So a string literal like this:

```
"$param.Value"
```

Will expand to:

```
"@{location=eastus2;...}.Value"
```

Notice that `$params` was evaluated and it's value substituted in the string, and the `.Value`-part is completely ignored.

To force PowerShell to evaluate expressions more complicated than simple variable references, use the `$()` subexpression operator:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=test]$($param.Value)"
```